# Chosen harvesthq resize width dynamically

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, width, jquery-chosen

How can you have a harvesthq Chosen dropdown with a dynamic width style?

By default it has a fixed width and if you try to modify it with CSS you will have several problems to reach a good result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just want to share my solution about how to resize chosen dropdown width on screen resize:

Firstly you have to add this style on your css:

```
#form_paciente{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Where *#form_paciente* is your selection ID.

After that add this script on your view:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    $('.chzn-container').innerWidth($('#selecciona_paciente_estadisticas_form').innerWidth());
    $('.chzn-search input').innerWidth($('#selecciona_paciente_estadisticas_form').innerWidth()-12);
    $('.chzn-drop').innerWidth($('#selecciona_paciente_estadisticas_form').innerWidth()-2);  
}, false);
```

In that case *#selecciona_paciente_estadisticas_form* is the form parent ID of *#form_paciente*

That's all!

Comment: Do you happen to have a solution for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425643/how-to-resize-a-chosen-jquery-dropdownlist-on-windows-resize

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: Perhaps removing chosen Dom and reattaching (see my answer below) would work for you?

Answer (score 40):

[This blog](http://dirtandrust.com/blog/chosen-js-rocks-now-with-responsive-goodness/) recommends the following:

> ```
> $("select").chosen({ width: '100%' }); // width in px, %, em, etc
> ```

Comment: I have that set but it doesn't resize based on the container: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425643/how-to-resize-a-chosen-jquery-dropdownlist-on-windows-resize

Comment: This setting does not accommodate dynamic width unless you reload the page. It is not responsive.

Comment: I believe the issue with resizing ChosenSelect is the fact that size is handled in javascript in the first place. I would highly recommend controlling the width in CSS when possible instead (which is possible in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the blog shout out https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327634/vinay-raghu. This solution I found is several years old so check Chosen documentation for more. But all it does is sets its width to 100% inline. Of course whatever container it's in needs to also be responsive for this to work, per Tormod's comment.

Answer (score 20):

this one worked for me, even with multiple select boxes on the screen:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      
   resizeChosen();
   jQuery(window).on('resize', resizeChosen);
});

function resizeChosen() {
   $(".chosen-container").each(function() {
       $(this).attr('style', 'width: 100%');
   });          
}
```

Year 2019. edit: Bear in mind that this answer was made 4 years ago when jQuery was popular library and when it was widely used. My advice is to use pure JS for everything made after this year. Don't neg rep historical answers that worked at the time they were written.

Comment: one line `$(window).on("resize", function() { $(".chosen-container").each(function() { $(this).attr("style", "width: 100%"); }); });`

Answer (score 5):

Although partly mentioned above, I would like to point out the following solution:

```
.chosen-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

This way your chosen widget will always be 100%, and resize accordingly. If you need it to be some other width, change the percentage or encapsulate the select itself with another element, and set the width on that element instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had a responsive form, which had lot of CSS rules with media queries, `!important`, etc and was using chosen with class inheritance option. On resizing, there were often conflicts between chosen and parent css and things would break. I came up with a simple solution that worked for me: recreate chosen dom on every window resize:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        doResize();
        jQuery(window).on('resize', doResize);
});


function doResize() {
     // Parent website's code, that would also reorganize select elements on the page
    jQuery("select.my-select").removeAttr("style"); // Remove display:none style added by chosen
    jQuery("select.my-select").removeClass("chzn-done"); // Remove chzn-done class added by chosen

    jQuery(".chzn-container").remove();
    jQuery("select.my-select").chosen({
                 width: '100%',
                 disable_search_threshold: 10,
                 inherit_select_classes : true
               });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @MSánchez's answer, I wrote the following to be more generic without referring to any IDs:

```
function processChosenContainer(myme) {
    myme.innerWidth(myme.parent().innerWidth() - 30);
}

function processChosenSearch(myme) {
    myme.innerWidth(myme.parent().parent().parent().innerWidth() - 13);
}

function processChosenDrop(myme) {
    myme.innerWidth(myme.parent().parent().innerWidth() - 32);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    //******Adjust Container Width********/
    var myObj = $('.chosen-container');
    myObj.each(function () {
        processChosenContainer($(this));
    });
    //******Adjust input search Width********/
    var myObj2 = $('.chosen-search input');
    myObj2.each(function () {
        processChosenSearch($(this));
    });
    //******Adjust drop Width********/
    var myObj3 = $('.chosen-drop');
    myObj3.each(function () {
        processChosenDrop($(this));
    });
}, false);
```

Also add to the select element "chosen-select-responsive" which is as follows:

```
.chosen-select-responsive {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Again, this is only a build-up on MSánchez's answer! thnx

Answer (score 1):

I am doing an app in MVC5.

Here is what I have done:

In the `.chosen-container` class i added

`width: 100% !important; // Assume that it is already 100%
    max-width: 280px; // It is the max-width of bootsrap form-control-class
    min-width: 0px; // It can go to 0`

It can go from 0 and 280px and I assume that the width is 100%.

This worked out completly responsive for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use width in percentage within single quotes:

```
<select chosen width="'100%'" ... ></select>
```

A responsive chosen using this technique can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RMAe8c?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple why I did it.

**JS:**

```
// Create Chosen Select Menus
setUpSelectMenus();

// Reset Chosen Select Menus when window changes size
window.addEventListener( "resize", function() { setUpSelectMenus(); } );

/**
 * Settings for Default Chosen Select Menus
 */
function setUpSelectMenus(){

    $( '.chosen-select' )
        .chosen( "destroy" ) // Need this to make responsive
        .chosen(
            {
                allow_single_deselect   : true,
                disable_search_threshold: 10
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I use is to use inherit_select_class.

HTML

```
<select class="input-xxlarge" />
```

JS

```
jQuery("[data-chosen]").chosen({
  inherit_select_classes : true
});
```

CSS

```
.input-xxlarge {
  width:530px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please put data-chosen attribute in html also to make it runable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this quick sniplet

```js
 $(window).resize(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen('destroy') ;
  $(".chosen-select").chosen() ;
 });
```

Granted there are more elegant ways to handle it. But it works.

Answer (score -1):

For me, what it really worked was this:

```
function resizeChosen() {
    var chosen = $("#dropdown_chosen");
    var max = chosen.parent().width();
    var currentWidth = chosen.width();
    var now = currentWidth + 20 / 100 * currentWidth;

    if (now <= max) {
        $("#dropdown_chosen").attr('style', "width: " + now + "px");
    }
}
```

and inside document.ready

```
dropdown.chosen().change(function() {
    resizeChosen();
});
```

where dropdown is id of the dropdown. You can also set width decrease on change event. #dropdown_chosen is created by chosen as follows:

dropdown - your dropdown id
append _chosen