# How to resize a chosen jquery dropdownlist on windows resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I have the following asp.net code which makes use of the jQuery chosen to customize the `dropdownlist`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlProvider" CssClass="setProvDDStyle" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlSpecialty" CssClass="chosen-select setProvDDStyle" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I use the following script to initialize the `dropdownlist`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
        '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
        '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
        '.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.setProvDDStyle
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I intentionally left the provider dropdownlist without the `chosen-select` style which creates the style. When I resize the browser window, you can see the width of the `dropdownlist` with the `chosen select` style does not resize based on the container. I added the above script inside the `windows.resize()` function but didn't really do anything.

How would I accomplish the styled dropdownlist to resize based on the size of the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrapped your Drop Down List inside a container DIV:

```
<div id="ddlSpecialtyContainer">
  <asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlSpecialty" CssClass="chosen-select setProvDDStyle" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Then I added a window `resize` event handler which resizes the dynamically generated jQuery chosen control inside the Drop Down List container.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var width = $("#ddlSpecialtyContainer")[0].offsetWidth + "px";
  $("#ddlSpecialtyContainer .chosen-container").css("width", width);
});
```

This seems to work as you have requested.

Comment: ddlSpecialtyContainer should be 100% width I presume?

Comment: If that's what you want it to be.

Comment: If you look at the source code for the jQuery chosen widget, you will see a function called `set_up_html`. This function is called when the chosen widget is generated and it applies a fixed width to the chosen widget based on the current size of your Drop Down List. This only runs once, so you have to add a resize event handler to alter the width of the chosen widget anytime the screen size changes.