# jQuery Chosen - Add multiple responsive widths to different select chosen box

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I have two select box, each having different reponsive width.
`width:45%` and `width:22%` . How to use jquery chosen for both elements.
In my project many components have `width:45%` only few are `22%`.
I am using `22%` inline with html like

```
<div style='width:22%'></div>
```

If I use

```
$("select").chosen({ width: '45%' });
```

SOURCE : [Chosen harvesthq resize width dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960690/chosen-harvesthq-resize-width-dynamically)

The above `div` width value also gets changed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

step-0: remove all width

step-1: add these lines to your js file:

```
var callback = function (){

   $('.chosen-container.chosen-container-single').innerWidth("100%"); 

};

$(document).ready(callback);

$(window).resize(callback);//responsive width
```